# "\G" failed to work in my navicat console

Tags: mysql, navicat

"\G" failed to work in my navicat console.  How do I use "\G" in navicat?

Comment: Cqn you show us your code and what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `\G` as a statement terminator to format results in vertical output is a feature of the `mysql` command line client.

I'm not a Navicat user, but it seems that it supports something they call **Form View** which is kind of similar.

https://www2.navicat.com/manual/online_manual/en/navicat/linux_manual/FormView.html

Comment: thank you bill. it seems that navicat do not suppot this feature.